# Using LINQ to populate a string with a single column value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a newbie both to C# and to LINQ and would appreciate a small push in the right direction.

Firstly, I have an Overrides SQL table (and a corresponding EF DB context), which has a Type, Value, and Override Value.  The idea is that for a particular kind ("Type") of override, the code can check a particular value and go see if there is an override value that should be used instead.

```
var branchOverrides = overridesSqlContext.Overrides
  .Where(q => q.Type == "Branch Override")
  .Select(s => new
    {
      s.Value,
      s.OverrideValue
    });
```

In this case, I want the list of different override values of the "Branch Override" type.  From there, I would like to be able to retrieve a specific override value at a given point within my code.  How can I query the branchOverrides variable I've created to be able to say something like:

```
string readingOverride = select OverrideValue from branchOverrides where Value = "Reading"
```

My code will need to be able to read various override values for different branches at different points, and being able to query the branchOverrides variable at any point would seem like the ideal approach.

Thank you for any assistance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Single()` on the query object you have:

```
string readingOverride = branchOverrides
    .Single(bo => bo.Value == "Reading")
    .OverrideValue;
```

This will throw an exception if an entry doesn't exist though so you probably want to use `SingleOrDefault` instead and check for a null return.

Also note that the `branchOverrides` object here is an `IQueryable<>` which means that every time you use it, it will send a query to the database. You may want to materialise that to a local list by adding `.ToList()` after the `Select(...)`. Alternatively, you may want to look at caching this data, especially if it's going to be used frequently.

Comment: Why would you use `.Single()` over `.First()`? Do you suspect there might be more than one?

Comment: @nvoigt It doesn't make sense to have multiple overrides for the same type.  If multiple are allowed, which one should be chosen?  Either there needs to be some way of picking which one of the many values they want, or there should only ever be one, so `Single` would be correct.  Why do you think it'd be appropriate to just chose one random override value among many possible values?

Comment: @Servy Because if this actually *is* a database query, then it's going to impact performance to check this condition *on every read* instead of once on insert.

Comment: @nvoigt While there is an overhead in the DB of calling `Single` (as it takes 2 values and throws if more than 1 returns) I don't think it's hugely relevant here. If performance was an issue, perhaps these values are needed all over the place and are accessed frequently, then you would be far better off caching the data locally.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want the entry with Value = "Reading" and Type="Branch Override":

```
var branchOverride = overridesSqlContext.Overrides
            .SingleOrdDefault(q => q.Type == "Branch Override"
                                && q.Value == "Reading")
            .Select(s => new
            {
                s.Value,
                s.OverrideValue
            });
if (branchOverride != null)
{
  // do whatever ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance issue is good to put .ToList() in the end of your LINQ expression if you need to iterante over that list too many times.

```
var branchOverrides = overridesSqlContext.Overrides
  .Where(q => q.Type == "Branch Override")
  .Select(s => new
    {
      s.Value,
      s.OverrideValue
    }).ToList();
```

If it you will load the entire list into the memory avoiding to execute the sql query to fetch the data if you need to iterate through your list.

Other thing that you can do is:

```
string readingOverride = string.Empty;

var branchOverride = branchOverrides.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "Reading");

if(branchOverride != null)
{
  readingOverride = branchOverride.OverrideValue;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If `Value` is unique within "Branch Override" perhaps you want to turn it to a dictionary for fast lookup

```
var branchOverrides = overridesSqlContext.Overrides
        .Where(q => q.Type == "Branch Override")
        .Select(s => new
        {
            s.Value,
            s.OverrideValue
        })
        .ToDictionary(k => k.Value, v => v.OverrideValue);
```

Then later on you can find the override value quickly and efficiently

```
var readingOverride = branchOverrides["Reading"];
```

Comment: Why would you copy all of the data into a list, only to immediately throw out that list and never use it for anything?

Comment: @Servy TBH i wasnt sure `ToDictionary` would translate to SQL so I simply materialized the list.

Comment: There is no `Queryable.ToDictionary` method, so it couldn't translate it into SQL even if the query provider wanted to try.  And if you want to make sure a method uses an `IEnumerable` overload rather than an `IQueryable` overload there's no need to copy the entire result set into a list and throw the list away to accomplish that.

Comment: @Servy you're right. I was just being lazy. Updated

Comment: `AsEnumerable` is less harmful, but equally unhelpful.  Again, *there is no `Queryable` implementation of `ToDictionary` in the first place*.

Comment: @Servy thats exactly the point. You probably *want* something like this to be a dictionary but you need to materialize the list to make it one.

Comment: No, you don't.  You don't need to materialize it into a list at all.  You don't need to call *any* methods on it to call` ToDictionary`, you just call `ToDictionary` and it works equally effectively, just without the added overhead.

Comment: I think what Servy is saying is that because `ToDictionary` isn't defined for queryable, it can be used exactly the same way that `ToList` is used. So the `AsEnumerable()` line here is pointless.

Comment: Ok, I thought that would try to convert it to sql.